# Codenameone closing a socket

Tags: codenameone

There seems to be no way of disconnecting a socket without causing a connection reset error on the server side.

I'm using the `com.codename1.io.Socket` and `com.codename1.io.SocketConnection` implementations within a tester app. My code is as follows:

```
private SpanLabel lblStatus;
private SpanLabel lblIncoming;
private CustomSocketConnection con;
private Thread tIncoming;

public ConnectForm() {
    con = getSocketConnection();
    Button btnConnect = getConnectButton();
    Button btnDisconnect = getDisconnectButton();
    Button btnSendMessage = getSendMessageButton();
    lblStatus = getInfoLabel();
    lblIncoming = getIncomingLabel();

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    addComponent(btnConnect);
    addComponent(btnDisconnect);
    addComponent(btnSendMessage);
    addComponent(lblStatus);
    addComponent(lblIncoming);
}

private Button getConnectButton() {
    Button btn = new Button("Connect (localhost)");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Socket.connect("localhost", 8687, con);
        }
    });
    return btn;
}

private Button getDisconnectButton() {
    Button btn = new Button("Disconnect");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //??? I don't know how to do this
            try {
                tIncoming.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tIncoming.interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
    return btn;
}

private Button getSendMessageButton() {
    Button btn = new Button("Send Message");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try {
                con.os.write("Hello".getBytes());
                con.os.write(Integer.parseInt("04", 16)); //end of transmit
                con.os.flush();
                lblStatus.setText("Message Sent");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return btn;
}

private SpanLabel getInfoLabel() {
    return new SpanLabel("Disconnected");
}

private SpanLabel getIncomingLabel() {
    return new SpanLabel("...");
}

private CustomSocketConnection getSocketConnection() {
    return new CustomSocketConnection();
}

class CustomSocketConnection extends SocketConnection {

    public OutputStream os;
    public InputStream is;

    @Override
    public void connectionError(int errorCode, String message) {
        lblStatus.setText("Error Connecting. ErrorCode: " + errorCode + " Message: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionEstablished(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        lblStatus.setText("Connected :)");
        this.is = is;
        this.os = os;
        spawnIncomingMessageWatcher();
    }
}

private void spawnIncomingMessageWatcher() {
    tIncoming = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String s = "";
            int eot = Integer.parseInt("04", 16);
            while (con.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    int temp;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    while (((temp = con.is.read()) != -1) && (temp != eot)) {
                        baos.write(temp);
                    }
                    lblIncoming.setText(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    tIncoming.start();
}
```

With the `getDisconnectButton()` method, I do not know how to properly disconnect from the server, as the `SocketConnection` object does not seem to have an appropriate method for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you call close() on either the Input- or OutputStream then you close the Socket, code from Socket.SocketInputStream class [link](https://github.com/shannah/cn1/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/Socket.java).

```
    public void close() throws IOException {
        closed = true;
        if(Util.getImplementation().isSocketConnected(impl)) {
            Util.getImplementation().disconnectSocket(impl);
            con.setConnected(false);
        }
    }
```

So first send close instruction to Server and then close a stream.

Hope this helps,